Excel: Counting instances in multiple columns, inside of a date range
I have an excel sheet with a sports schedule that has multiple events per day.
I need a formula to count the number of instances that a name appears within Column J and Column K, within a date range within the last 4 days, according to the Date Value column in Column S. And if the name appears 3 times in the last 4 days, I want the formula to return a True value, in order to check off a box in Column E.
I have tried many iterations of:
=if(countifs("ColumnJ","ColumnJTeam", "ColumnK","ColumnKTeam", "ColumnS","ColumnSDateValue-4") , 1, 0)  

Basically trying to search through Column J and Column K ranges for the team name, but only through the last 4 days... But I cant get it to output in the correct lines.
Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

*Note: In the screenshot, the yellow highlighted rows indicate the rows that SHOULD receive a checkmark, in order to verify the formula is working as intended.
Also, I can share a copy of the workbook, if requested!

Your formula uses named ranges (I assume) which makes it hard to parse. Where are the ranges for "ColumnJTeam", "ColumnKTeam", etc...?

Chicago Bulls shouldn't be marked? Rows: 10,24,32?

@Blackcat hello! Yeah, they would also be marked, but I was focusing on getting the formula for Column E dialed in before I populated it into "Home Team 3-in-4" in the hidden Column N.

@cybernetic.nomad the formula listed was mostly trying to convey what type of information was SUPPOSED to go in those locations in the formula.
So in reality, it would be something like : =if(countifs(J:J,J28, K:K,J28, S:S,S28-4) , 1, 0)

Why it doesn't work: 1. Your date criteria will only select a date that is 4 days before the date in S and you need to select a range of dates. 2. COUNTIFS effectively AND's the criteria whereas what you need is to OR the teams related criteria and then AND the date related criteria.

This is wat too much typing to reproduce. You should include data as markdown table https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Your question is a little confusing to me as your example seems to be counting the appearance only of ROAD TEAM in either the ROAD TEAM or HOME TEAM columns.
If that is what you mean, then the following formula returns that count. Note that I used a Table with structured references, but you can switch back to normal addressing if you prefer.
To base your count on the HOME TEAM column, merely change the last argument of the formula matches=... appropriately.
=LET(
    matches, FILTER(
        Schedule[[ROAD TEAM]:[HOME TEAM]],
        (Schedule[DATE] >= (Schedule[@DATE] - 4)) *
            (Schedule[DATE] <= Schedule[@DATE])
    ),
    a, matches = Schedule[@[ROAD TEAM]],
    SUM(a * 1)
)

seems to return the count you are looking for. Note also that I used the Date column in your schedule table instead of Column S, as they appear to be identical

And, of course,  if you want to return a boolean, you would just compare the results of that formula to what you are looking for. You don't write what you want returned if the count is less than 3, but I'm sure you can figure things out from here.
